# Jasmine jQuery: Using toBeHidden() and toBeVisible()

Tags: jquery, jasmine, bdd, jasmine-jquery

I need help working with the `toBeHidden()` and `toBeVisible()` methods of jQuery-Jasmine.

When a user checks a checkbox, a text field should slide down -- and unchecking slides it up. The text field is hidden when the page loads.

The code is working fine in my application, but I'm confused by the results I'm getting in my tests.

The first two are working -- checking if the field is hidden by default and visible on first change:

```
expect($('#text-field')).toBeHidden(); // passes

$('#checkbox').prop('checked', true).change();
expect($('#text-field')).toBeVisible(); // passes
```

But when the checkbox is unchecked, the text field slides up in the real version but fails in my test:

```
$('#checkbox').prop('checked', false).change();
expect($('#text-field')).toBeHidden(); // fails
```

I've also tried:

```
expect($('#text-field')).not.toBeVisible(); // fails
expect($('#text-field')).toHaveCss({display: "none"}); // fails
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or know what else I need to do to help Jasmine see that the text field slid up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably have the same problem that I did, your view is standard invisible in your tests because it is not attached to the DOM. Try this in your test:

```
$('body').append(view);
```

Answer (score 5):

`.toBeHidden` and `.toBeVisible` or not opposites, see the [Jasmine-jquery docs](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery/blob/master/README.md).
I advice you to use `.toBeHidden` and `.not.toBeHidden` in conjunction.

Note that `.toBeHidden` does `this.actual.is(':hidden')` which means that it consumes no space (https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/), so it expects your fixtures to be appended to the body.

`.toBeVisible` checks for `this.actual.is(':visible')` which, according to the jQuery docs, means that it checks if the element has `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0`. So it could consume space, but should has no visibility.